# Failed to run `usb start` in u-boot with error of !CSWSIGNATURE

Tags: usb, u-boot

I am working on an embedded Linux system with u-boot (2013-07) as bootloader in an SOC platform, now I tried to support USB disk in u-boot, so I did some porting and HW configuration.

I *think* the u-boot can detect the USB disk, but an error was hit when I ran `usb start` in the command line.

I enabled the DEBUG and BBB_XPORT_TRACE in `common/usb_storage.c` to get more infor on the errors, here they come (the CACHELINE_SIZE is 32 in this SOC).

```
0# usb start
(Re)start USB...
scanning bus 0 for devices... 2 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... i=0
i=1


USB Mass Storage device detected
Transport: Bulk/Bulk/Bulk
Endpoints In 1 Out 2 Int 0
Get Max LUN -> len = 1, result = 0
 address 2
COMMAND phase
dir 1 lun 0 cmdlen 12 cmd 83faf2a0 datalen 36 pdata 83b4a000
cmd[0] 0x12 cmd[1] 0x0 cmd[2] 0x0 cmd[3] 0x0 cmd[4] 0x24 cmd[5] 0x0 cmd[6] 0x0 cmd[7] 0x0 cmd[8] 0x0 cmd[9] 0x0 cmd[10] 0x0 cmd[11] 0x0
DATA phase
pdata[0] 0x0 pdata[1] 0x80 pdata[2] 0x6 pdata[3] 0x12 pdata[4] 0x43 pdata[5] 0x0 pdata[6] 0x0 pdata[7] 0x0 pdata[8] 0x53 pdata[9] 0x61 pdata[10] 0x6e pdata[11] 0x44 pdata[12] 0x69 pdata[13] 0x73 pdata[14] 0x6b pdata[15] 0x0 pdata[16] 0x43 pdata[17] 0x72 pdata[18] 0x75 pdata[19] 0x7a pdata[20] 0x65 pdata[21] 0x72 pdata[22] 0x20 pdata[23] 0x42 pdata[24] 0x6c pdata[25] 0x61 pdata[26] 0x64 pdata[27] 0x65 pdata[28] 0x0 pdata[29] 0x0 pdata[30] 0x0 pdata[31] 0x0 pdata[32] 0x31 pdata[33] 0x2e pdata[34] 0x30 pdata[35] 0x30
STATUS phase
ptr[0] 0x0 ptr[1] 0x80 ptr[2] 0x6 ptr[3] 0x12 ptr[4] 0x43 ptr[5] 0x0 ptr[6] 0x0 ptr[7] 0x0 ptr[8] 0x53 ptr[9] 0x61 ptr[10] 0x6e ptr[11] 0x44 ptr[12] 0x69
XXXXXXXXXXXx csw@83b49f80,  CSWSig = 0x12068000, result: 0
!CSWSIGNATURE
BBB_reset
BBB_reset result 0: status 0 reset
BBB_reset result 0: status 0 clearing IN endpoint
BBB_reset result 0: status 0 clearing OUT endpoint
BBB_reset done
inquiry returns -1
COMMAND phase
dir 1 lun 0 cmdlen 12 cmd 83faf2a0 datalen 36 pdata 83b4a000
cmd[0] 0x12 cmd[1] 0x0 cmd[2] 0x0 cmd[3] 0x0 cmd[4] 0x24 cmd[5] 0x0 cmd[6] 0x0 cmd[7] 0x0 cmd[8] 0x0 cmd[9] 0x0 cmd[10] 0x0 cmd[11] 0x0
DATA phase
usb_bulk_msg error status 0
BBB_reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing IN endpoint
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing OUT endpoint
BBB_reset done
inquiry returns -1
COMMAND phase
dir 1 lun 0 cmdlen 12 cmd 83faf2a0 datalen 36 pdata 83b4a000
cmd[0] 0x12 cmd[1] 0x0 cmd[2] 0x0 cmd[3] 0x0 cmd[4] 0x24 cmd[5] 0x0 cmd[6] 0x0 cmd[7] 0x0 cmd[8] 0x0 cmd[9] 0x0 cmd[10] 0x0 cmd[11] 0x0
usb_stor_BBB_comdat:usb_bulk_msg error
failed to send CBW status 0
BBB_reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing IN endpoint
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing OUT endpoint
BBB_reset done
inquiry returns -1
COMMAND phase
dir 1 lun 0 cmdlen 12 cmd 83faf2a0 datalen 36 pdata 83b4a000
cmd[0] 0x12 cmd[1] 0x0 cmd[2] 0x0 cmd[3] 0x0 cmd[4] 0x24 cmd[5] 0x0 cmd[6] 0x0 cmd[7] 0x0 cmd[8] 0x0 cmd[9] 0x0 cmd[10] 0x0 cmd[11] 0x0
usb_stor_BBB_comdat:usb_bulk_msg error
failed to send CBW status 0
BBB_reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing IN endpoint
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing OUT endpoint
BBB_reset done
inquiry returns -1
COMMAND phase
dir 1 lun 0 cmdlen 12 cmd 83faf2a0 datalen 36 pdata 83b4a000
cmd[0] 0x12 cmd[1] 0x0 cmd[2] 0x0 cmd[3] 0x0 cmd[4] 0x24 cmd[5] 0x0 cmd[6] 0x0 cmd[7] 0x0 cmd[8] 0x0 cmd[9] 0x0 cmd[10] 0x0 cmd[11] 0x0
usb_stor_BBB_comdat:usb_bulk_msg error
failed to send CBW status 0
BBB_reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 reset
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing IN endpoint
BBB_reset result -1: status 0 clearing OUT endpoint
BBB_reset done
inquiry returns -1
error in inquiry
i=2
0 Storage Device(s) found
        scanning usb for video devices... 0 Video Device(s) found
```

And the `usb info` showed as follows,

```
# usb info
1: Hub,  USB Revision 1.10
 -  U-Boot Root Hub
 - Class: Hub
 - PacketSize: 8  Configurations: 1
 - Vendor: 0x0000  Product 0x0000 Version 0.0
   Configuration: 1
   - Interfaces: 1 Self Powered 0mA
     Interface: 0
     - Alternate Setting 0, Endpoints: 1
     - Class Hub
     - Endpoint 1 In Interrupt MaxPacket 2 Interval 255ms

2: Mass Storage,  USB Revision 2.0
 - SanDisk Cruzer Blade 040172060905221??653
 - Class: (from Interface) Mass Storage
 - PacketSize: 64  Configurations: 1
 - Vendor: 0x0781  Product 0x5567 Version 1.0
   Configuration: 1
   - Interfaces: 1 Bus Powered 200mA
     Interface: 0
     - Alternate Setting 0, Endpoints: 2
     - Class Mass Storage, Transp. SCSI, Bulk only
     - Endpoint 1 In Bulk MaxPacket 512
     - Endpoint 2 Out Bulk MaxPacket 512
```

I tried to add 1000ms delay in `usb_stor_BBB_transport()`, but no effect.
I am pretty new to USB stack in U-boot, so what is the possibel reason of this error and what could I do to fix it?

#### updated with logs from a working SOC

I tried the u-boot code base on a similar SOC, where it is working. I got following logs of `usb start`, and there is NO such error in the `STATUS phase`, i.e. it got the correct `CSWSIGNATURE`.

```
USB0:   scanning bus 0 for devices... 2 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... i=0
i=1


USB Mass Storage device detected
Transport: Bulk/Bulk/Bulk
Endpoints In 1 Out 2 Int 0
Get Max LUN -> len = 1, result = 0
 address 2
COMMAND phase
dir 1 lun 0 cmdlen 12 cmd 87faba20 datalen 36 pdata 86efb000
cmd[0] 0x12 cmd[1] 0x0 cmd[2] 0x0 cmd[3] 0x0 cmd[4] 0x24 cmd[5] 0x0 cmd[6] 0x0 cmd[7] 0x0 cmd[8] 0x0 cmd[9] 0x0 cmd[10] 0x0 cmd[11] 0x0
DATA phase
pdata[0] 0x0 pdata[1] 0x80 pdata[2] 0x6 pdata[3] 0x12 pdata[4] 0x43 pdata[5] 0x0 pdata[6] 0x0 pdata[7] 0x0 pdata[8] 0x53 pdata[9] 0x61 pdata[10] 0x6e pdata[11] 0x44 pdata[12] 0x69 pdata[13] 0x73 pdata[14] 0x6b pdata[15] 0x0 pdata[16] 0x43 pdata[17] 0x72 pdata[18] 0x75 pdata[19] 0x7a pdata[20] 0x65 pdata[21] 0x72 pdata[22] 0x20 pdata[23] 0x42 pdata[24] 0x6c pdata[25] 0x61 pdata[26] 0x64 pdata[27] 0x65 pdata[28] 0x0 pdata[29] 0x0 pdata[30] 0x0 pdata[31] 0x0 pdata[32] 0x31 pdata[33] 0x2e pdata[34] 0x30 pdata[35] 0x30
STATUS phase
ptr[0] 0x55 ptr[1] 0x53 ptr[2] 0x42 ptr[3] 0x53 ptr[4] 0x0 ptr[5] 0x0 ptr[6] 0x0 ptr[7] 0x0 ptr[8] 0x0 ptr[9] 0x0 ptr[10] 0x0 ptr[11] 0x0 ptr[12] 0x0
XXXXXXXXXXXx csw@86efaf80,  CSWSig = 0x53425355, result: 0
inquiry returns 0
```